# Timer not starting unless function hasn't been called for certain amount of time

Tags: c#, discord.net

When the command `.checked` is not done for 15 minutes, I would like a timer to spam a message every minute. Right now I have it set to some ridiculously fast amount for testing purposes. `Check()` is called when .checked is done.

I tried doing something like this:

```
      public static void Check()
            {
                MinecraftClient.ChatBots.DiscordWallTimer.TimerOn = false;
                Program.StartTimer();
            }

            public static System.Timers.Timer EnableTimer;

            public static Task StartTimer()
            {
                EnableTimer = new Timer()
                {

                    Interval = 15 * 1000,
                    AutoReset = false,
                    Enabled = true
                };
                EnableTimer.Elapsed += OnTimerTicked;

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            public static void OnTimerTicked(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                MinecraftClient.ChatBots.DiscordWallTimer.TimerOn = true;
                MinecraftClient.ChatBots.DiscordWallTimer.StartTimer();

            }
```

And having this in my timer class:

```
public class DiscordWallTimer
    {

        public static bool TimerOn;

        public static System.Timers.Timer wallTimer;

        internal static Task StartTimer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wall timer has started");

            wallTimer = new Timer()
            {

                Interval = 5*1000,
                AutoReset = true,
                Enabled = TimerOn
            };
            wallTimer.Elapsed += OnTimerTicked;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private static void OnTimerTicked(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TimerOn == true)
            {
                Program.SendAlertDiscord();
            }
        }

    }
```

Only problem is that the alert still sends if .check has been done recently (I think for testing I set it to 15 seconds.)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you point me to the `DateTime` variable where you are storing the UTC date / time when `.check` was done most recently?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on each of your `StartTimer` methods, and run the code. Run it for 15 minutes. How many times do each breakpoint get hit?

Comment: Just a small thing: methods with the name `On*` (like your `OnTimerTicked`) are typically the methods that raise the events and not handle them. That's the normal .NET convention.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a library designed to do this kind of thing rather than mucking around with timers - which can be hard.

Try Microsoft's Reactive Framework:

```
private static Subject<Unit> _check = new Subject<Unit>();
private static IDisposable _subscription = null;

private static void SetUp()
{
    _subscription =
        _check
            .Select(x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15.0), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0)))
            .Switch()
            .Subscribe(x => Program.SendAlertDiscord());
}

public static void Check()
{
    _check.OnNext(Unit.Default);
}
```

That's it. Just call `SetUp` once and then whenever you call `Check()` you'll start a 15 minute timer that then spams every minute. Any call to `Check()` will reset the timer automatically.

And call `_subscription.Dispose();` if you want to shut down the code.

Just NuGet "System.Reactive" to get the bits and then add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` to your code.

If you have any threading issues let me know any I'll help get the code to marshall to the right thread for you.

Comment: I dont know reactive but its seems great!!

Answer (score 0):

in fact you dont stop the timer DiscordWallTimer, you just do some modifications and all will be ok and
You dont need the variable TimerOn

```
 public static void Check()
        {
           // the first time walltimer doesnt exist
           if (MinecraftClient.ChatBots.DiscordWallTimer.wallTimer != null)
           {
                MinecraftClient.ChatBots.DiscordWallTimer.wallTimer.Stop();
           }

            Program.StartTimer();
        }

public class DiscordWallTimer
{
        public static System.Timers.Timer wallTimer;

        internal static Task StartTimer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wall timer has started");

            wallTimer = new Timer()
            {
                Interval = 5*1000,
                AutoReset = true,
                Enabled = true                     // <- keep True
            };
            wallTimer.Elapsed += OnTimerTicked;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        private static void OnTimerTicked(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Program.SendAlertDiscord();
        }
}
```